# javascript post 500 serrver internal error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

i'm using ajax and web methods and when i execute this code appear an error thar say 
post POST  500 (Internal Server Error) 
but this path Exist!!!

this code is i'm using in this moment

```
function fnSendID() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GMap.aspx/SendCommands",
            data: '{IDMobile: "'+$("#<%=Ddl_MobileCustomer.ClientID%>").val()+'"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                console.log("Entro : " + response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log("Fallo : " + response.d);
            }
        });

<WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function SendCommands(ByVal IDMobile As String) As String
        'iIDMobile = GetMobileID(iIDMobile)
        Dim sResponse As String = IDMobile + "Buenas"
        Return sResponse
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A 500 means the path you are hitting caused an error on the server side not that the path doesn't exist.

Comment: POST http://localhost:12289/GMap.aspx/SendCommands 500 (Internal Server Error) this path if exist!!!

Answer (score 0):

Debug the code and set a breakpoint at Dim sResponse As String = IDMobile + "Buenas".
Does it reach here? Is there any exception before the return?